# Excel Read/Write in Python without any external package

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7, read-write

I am working on company server where Python has been installed for us. Now I want process the excel files but I can not install any external packages like Pandas or Xlrd. So is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is converting the Excel files to e.g. csv (feasibility depending on their content, of course) an option? Otherwise, if I'm not mistaken, xlsx is basically a zip file and the data is kept in an xml file inside of the archive. Both zip and xml can be processed natively by Python. But I don't think you're going to enjoy the process…

Comment: Well I have excel file which would be provided as input to Python script to process. If converting it to CSV was an option then it could be easily processed as normal text file but unfortunately its not.

Comment: @adesh are you sure installing Python packages is not an option? If the only problem is that you can't install packages *globally*, then that's okay because you can install packages locally as well (without root/admin privileges).

Comment: @sumit could you throw some light on that? How can i install python packages locally?

Comment: @adesh use [a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments).

Comment: Thanks @Sumit I will have look and check if it is feasible solution. Meanwhile if anyone has done excel processing with Native Python, please guide me.

Comment: @adesh xlrd is 100% pure native Python. Just because it's available as an external package doesn't mean it's not Python. Like Kristof said, you could write your own code, but that would be reinventing the wheel, which is wholly unnecessary and almost always a bad idea in software development.

Comment: @adesh if you still want to write it by hand, maybe because you want to learn how it works, take a look at the [source code of xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd). Like I said, it's pure Python. But do consider again if writing the code by hand is what you really want.